# Motion graphs problem

Tags: acceleration

I am thinking that options a and 
c must not be the right answer since they obviously show that a=0,however, I don't understand how does it come up those x-axis in options b and d from the motion equations. Which one of them represents a uniformly accelerated motion with a ≠0? Can anyone please teach me?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every graph xy can be intrepreted as a function y(x)

**Option a refers to**

$s=v*t$

Where v is costant

**Option b refers to**

$v=k*s^2$

Where k has dimensions $1/(seconds*meters)$ which I have never personally encountered and have no idea what it is

**Option c refers to**

$s^2=h*t+q$

where h has dimesions $meters^2/seconds$ (no idea what that could be)

**Option d refers to**

$v=\sqrt{a}*\sqrt{s}$

solve for $s$ and you get

$s=v^2/a$

We know that $v=at$ because $v(s=0)=0$ so it has no initial velocity. Therefore

$s=at^2$

Which is the uniformly accelerated motion, so d is the correct answer. I hope everything is clear